# Is encryption in C# cross platform in mono?

Tags: c#, mono, cross-platform, monogame

Are the security encryption classes in .NET Useable on mono run times? (In particular monogame implementations that use mono run time on Mac etc.)

I am mostly interested in if I can use the [AES] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx) class because I have used it before.

Would I be able to encrypt strings (such as config data) to obfuscate it and then save that as a file and later decrypt it back in the program.

Comment: Begging the question, how will you keep the encryption key secret?

Comment: I don't know yet best practices. Just to get it working it will be in source code but I know for a released product that is a bad idea.

Comment: Define your threat model from curious teen to well funded nation, they define the value to the attacker, the user and yourself. After that you will have a better idea of the security needed. It may turn out having it in the source code meets your needs or not. Keep in mind that there is no 100% secure solution. If this is on a server it is easier to defend ad if you own the server you can add a low-end HSM or perhaps there is a TPM included in the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ... you can use these classes on mono-backed platforms such as MacOS :)

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Security.Cryptography.Aes/

*edit*: @zaph makes an excellent point in the comments ... there are libraries, such as [PCLCrypto](https://github.com/aarnott/pclcrypto/#pclcrypto) that use the native libraries on each platform for this very reason :)

Comment: If you use these iOS or macOS the performance mat be much worse than using the Apple Common Crypto functions. Depending on the implementation and platform they can be up to 1000 times slower. An iPhone 6s can encrypt with Common Crypto at 430 MB/s, benchmark the Mono classes.

Comment: Great point @zaph ... updated answer to include a link to a great library that takes this into account.

Comment: Does PCLCrypto use the Common Crypto libraries? In particular does it use the iPhone hardware encryption engine?

Comment: offhand, I couldn't tell you ... but if you read the project's README, it mentions that the PCL itself doesn't actually implement any cryptography, so it's using native library (search the code for `SecurityLibrary` in the code to see what APIs it is manually binding to on ios)

Comment: I downloaded the project and searched for "CommonCrypto", "CCCrypt" (the symmetric encryption function, it is a "C") and found nothing so I doubt it is using Common Crypto. A benchmark is in order to verify the performance for AES.

Comment: The extra detail of performance between cross-platform libraries is excellent additional information.